# Thread parallelism and single CPU system

Tags: parallel-processing

Does parallelism in threads benefit processes in a single CPU system?

I know that parallelism in threads definitely benefits multi-CPU systems but what about a single CPU system?

Answer (score 0):

YES It does benefit, a thread waiting on `IO` can be suspended and a thread that needs to do processing can be allocated the CPU